# What constitutes a concerning large value for the seq_scan column in PostgreSQL's pg_stat_user_tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-indexes

I'm trying to identify which tables in my Postgres DB are missing indexes, for which I'm looking at the `pg_stat_user_tables`. I read that "large" values in the `seq_scan` column are an indicator of missing indexes, but I'm looking for more clarity on what constitutes "large".

Is it an absolute value, or is it dependent on the number of rows in the table?  As an example, when running this query, the largest values I see for `seq_scan` and `tup_per_scan` are 7,617,366 and 3,253,864 respectively.

```
SELECT relname,
       seq_scan,
       seq_tup_read / seq_scan AS tup_per_scan
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE seq_scan > 0;
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not an absolute value but 3M tuples per scan sure sounds like a lot. Question is, how the table is queried most frequently and how to construct an index that would improve performance of those queries. You might want to take a look at [`log_min_duration_statement`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN) and start sampling long running statements.

Comment: If a sequential scan is good or bad, depends on the queries you execute. Not on the indexes. It's completely useless to create any index on a table, when you always need all the data from that table, without sorting or so. So before solving a problem, you should have a problem. And a sequential scan is not a problem, it's just how the table was read.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to take into account since when these statistics are collected:

```
SELECT datname, stats_reset
FROM pg_stat_database;
```

It makes a difference if those 7 million scans happened in a month or five years.

I would correlate this finding with the queries in `pg_stat_statements` that have the highest `total_exec_time`: if one of your top statements involves this query, look at the execution plan. Perhaps an index can reduce your overall resource consumption.